# JavaFX - How to bind Task progress property to another property within the call() method

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to figure out how to bind the progress property of a Task to the property of an object being used inside the Task's call function.

Conceptually, I have an object that does a certain amount of work and exposes its progress via DoubleProperties.  Since I would like to to do this (long running) task off of the JavaFX main thread, I would like to wrap it in a Task object and be able to show the progress of the underlying object.  However it seems like the only way to update the progress in a Task is through the updateProgress() method, which takes concrete numbers instead of Observables.  Similarly, the progressProperty is exposed as a ReadOnlyDoubleProperty, so I can't set the property that way, nor override the progressProperty() method to return the property I would like to use to display progress.

More concretely, this is would I would like to do:

```
final FooBuilder builder = new FooBuilder();
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {

         //
         // bind to FooBuilders progress property here...but how?
         // Progress of doLongBuildThing is reflected in an exposed
         // DoubleProperty in the FooBuilder class.
         //
         //       

         builder.doLongBuildingThing(); 
         return null;
    }           
};
```

This seems like such a basic thing that it should be pretty easy, yet I am not seeing a straightforward way to accomplish it. Any help would be appreciated.

TIA.

- chooks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
builder.progressProperty().addListener((obs, oldProgress, newProgress) -> 
    updateProgress(newProgress, 1.0));
```

(assuming `FooBuilder`'s progress property ranges from 0 to 1).

Comment: Thanks - this worked fine.  Since the builder is longer lived than the caller, I am assigning the lambdas to objects so that I can removeListener() at the end of the call method. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since your already doing the progress stuff in your object just divide by the max work to get a percentage and bind it to the [progress indicator's progress](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ProgressIndicator.html#progressProperty) directly (a DoubleProperty).  Wrap the binding in a Platform.runLater for safety and you're basically doing all the work of setProgress() in task.

Comment: I am using the ControlFX Dialogs API (Dialogs.showWorkerProgress) so I do not have access to the underlying progress bar, otherwise I think this would be the way to go.